# log4j: how to set more packages logging into two file appenders, one with INFO threshold, the other with DEBUG threshold

Tags: java, logging, rollingfileappender, log4j2

I have two java app working together.
I'm trying to configure my log4j.properties file to have two RollingFileAppender catching same packages but with different log levels.
I want `it.pack.subpack1`, `it.pack.subpack2`, `it.pack.subpack3` log to two different file appenders, one catching all at DEBUG and above, one catching all at INFO and above.
I did the trick for appB but it doesn't work for appA. Why?
My properties file looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO

#appA INFO file appender
log4j.appender.bocfe=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.bocfe.File=${server.log.dir}/bocfe.log
log4j.appender.bocfe.Append=true
log4j.appender.bocfe.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.bocfe.MaxFileSize=15MB
log4j.appender.bocfe.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.bocfe.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.bocfe.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%c{1}] %p - %m%n

#appA DEBUG file appender
log4j.appender.bocfe-debug=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.bocfe-debug.File=${server.log.dir}/bocfe-debug.log
log4j.appender.bocfe-debug.Append=true
log4j.appender.bocfe-debug.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.bocfe-debug.MaxFileSize=15MB
log4j.appender.bocfe-debug.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.bocfe-debug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.bocfe-debug.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%c{1}] %p - %m%n

#appB INFO file appender
log4j.appender.bocws=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.bocws.File=${server.log.dir}/bocws.log
log4j.appender.bocws.Append=true
log4j.appender.bocws.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.bocws.MaxFileSize=15MB
log4j.appender.bocws.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.bocws.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.bocws.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%c{1}] %p - %m%n

#appB DEBUG file appender
log4j.appender.bocws-debug=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.bocws-debug.File=${server.log.dir}/bocws-debug.log
log4j.appender.bocws-debug.Append=true
log4j.appender.bocws-debug.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.bocws-debug.MaxFileSize=15MB
log4j.appender.bocws-debug.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.bocws-debug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.bocws-debug.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%c{1}] %p - %m%n

#loggers
log4j.logger.com.eclipsesource.json=DEBUG, bocfe, bocfe-debug
log4j.logger.it.secservizi.boc=DEBUG, bocfe, bocfe-debug
log4j.logger.it.secservizi.abgmf.communication=DEBUG, bocfe, bocfe-debug
log4j.logger.it.sec.ws.boc=DEBUG, bocws, bocws-debug

#additivity
log4j.additivity.com.eclipsesource.json=false
log4j.additivity.it.secservizi.boc=false
log4j.additivity.it.sec.ws.boc=false
log4j.logger.it.secservizi.abgmf.communication=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try adding the appender to log4j.rootLogger?

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, bocfe, bocfe-debug
```

Comment: Yes I can but is this the only way to solve? Where is the problem on my file? It looks like it skip these two rows
`log4j.logger.com.eclipsesource.json=DEBUG, bocfe, bocfe-debug
log4j.logger.it.secservizi.boc=DEBUG, bocfe, bocfe-debug`

Comment: I tried "log4j.logger.com.eclipsesource.json=DEBUG, bocfe, bocfe-debug" in my environment. It did work. My properties removed the ${server.log.dir} variables, changed the class name to gp.test.Main which outputs the debug message by calling Logger.getLogger(Main.class).debug(). I also specified the property file in the JVM option like "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/D:/eclipsews/workspace/Test/test.properties"